# Struggling with Google Android API login and libcurl/curl

Tags: google-api, openssl, libcurl

I'm writing a small C application to work with Google Keep. I used Python-written [gkeepapi](https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi) which in turn uses [gpsoauth](https://github.com/simon-weber/gpsoauth) as a reference. All HTTPS-related code can be found [here](https://github.com/simon-weber/gpsoauth/blob/master/gpsoauth/__init__.py).

For HTTPS I use libcurl (and also test it from curl CLI). For master login I perform a query with the following body (stripped):

> accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=USERNAME%40gmail.com&has_permission=1&add_account=1&EncryptedPassw=AFcb4KRFBAu...6_9jal31XKdZHZkg%3D%3D&service=ac2dm&source=android&androidId=31021392710718&device_country=us&operatorCountry=us&lang=en&sdk_version=17&client_sig=38918a453d07199354f8b19af05ec6562ced5788&callerSig=38918a453d07199354f8b19af05ec6562ced5788&droidguard_results=dummy123

This unfortunately results in 403 with "Error=BadAuthentication".

The same query with same body and seemingly same SSL context options, headers, etc. from gpsoauth works just fine:

```
>>> import gkeepapi; keep = gkeepapi.Keep(); keep.login('USER@gmail.com', '...')
accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=USER%40gmail.com&has_permission=1&add_account=1&EncryptedPasswd=AFcb4KRFBAu...6_9jal31XKdZHZkg%3D%3D&service=ac2dm&source=android&androidId=31021392710718&device_country=us&operatorCountry=us&lang=en&sdk_version=17&client_sig=38918a453d07199354f8b19af05ec6562ced5788&callerSig=38918a453d07199354f8b19af05ec6562ced5788&droidguard_results=dummy123


SID=BAD_COOKIE
LSID=BAD_COOKIE
Auth=TwiJFLqwaaPQrJCtBbiDfK9CUdJN6o4GyHMY4h8B-vTEuL8WAR2M...Gwu5Yufw6gDfxPZqBpw02OIcloqccdDrt5F-9DkRAk9J79Sgf3gTZI1Qes5chgs3b3r5QmIw702ckA=
services=mail,friendview,android,youtube,cl,talk,memento,mymaps,omaha,sierra,googleplay,print,blogger,multilogin,hist,jotspot,ah,dynamite,uif,g1phonebackup,domains
firstName=...
```

And so on. To double check I even tried hard-coding my generated body into Python code - and it succeeds there as well.

libcurl-related code in my small program:

```
static CURL* curl_setup(void) {
  CURL* curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (!curl) panic("curl_easy_init() failed");

  headers = curl_slist_append(NULL, "User-Agent: GoogleAuth/1.4");
  headers = curl_slist_append(
      headers, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                   "https://android.clients.google.com/auth");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "ECDHE+AESGCM:ECDHE+CHACHA20:DHE+AESGCM:DHE+CHACHA20:ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!DSS");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN, 0L);

  return curl;
}
...
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body);
  resp = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

OpenSSL library compiled into Python and curl is of the same version:

```
bash-5.1$ python3.9 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021

bash-5.1$ curl -V
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1m zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 c-ares/1.18.1 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.1 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.46.0 OpenLDAP/2.4.59
```

So far I have no new ideas for now :-) My primary suspect is some TLS-level incompatibility but at glance I have found nothing. Any suggestion on further debugging would be welcome!

Thanks!